# Sum of two $n^{th}$ powers modulo p

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does this have a solution
$x^n + y^n \equiv a (\text{mod}\: p) \:\forall \:a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and for every prime $p$ and for any $n$

Comment: I know it is true for n=2

Comment: If $p$ is prime, then $x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}$ is either $0$, $1$ or $2$ modulo $p$ (from Fermat's little theorem, because each term is either $0$ or $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not have a solution for any $a, p, n$. Look, for instance, at $x^3+y^3 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ or $x^4 + y^4\equiv 3\pmod 5$.

Comment: @Sam123 These two examples are so small that brute force works just fine. Calulate all fourth powers modulo $5$ (they're all $0$ or $1$), and all third powers modulo $7$ (they're all $0$ or $\pm 1$), and see that adding two of them only gives a limited number of possible results.